# First index of 2D-Array increases without any explicit increment

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, increment, decrement

I have a for Loop, in which I want to increase the second index of a 2 dimensional Array and want to have a static first index:

```
String[][] grid = new String[7][6];

inject(0);

public void inject(int column){
    for(int i=5;i>-1;i--){
        if(grid[column][i] == null){
            if(player.equals("red")){
                grid[column][i] = "red";
                System.out.println("column: " + column + " i: " + i);
                break;
            }
            if(player.equals("yellow")){
                grid[column][i] = "yellow";
                System.out.println("column: " + column + " i: " + i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected Output of the console (if

```
grid[0][5]="yellow"; grid[0][4]="red";
```

): 
column: 0 i: 5 
column: 0 i: 4 
column: 0 i: 3

Actual Output: 
column: 0 i: 3 
column: 1 i: 5 
column: 2 i: 5 
column: 3 i: 5 
column: 4 i: 5 
column: 5 i: 5 
column: 6 i: 5

Why does column increase, I have no increment for column defined. I only want to check in one column what the last "null" array-field index is.

Calling of inject:

```
public void tasteReagieren(int key){
//Method of EngineAlpha to handle keyboard actions
    switch(key){
    case Taste._1: einwerfen(0);
    case Taste._2: einwerfen(1);
    case Taste._3: einwerfen(2);
    case Taste._4: einwerfen(3);
    case Taste._5: einwerfen(4);
    case Taste._6: einwerfen(5);
    case Taste._7: einwerfen(6);
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(int i=5;i>-1;i++)` doesn't look right, and don't compare strings with `==`.

Comment: Don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two object references are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Comment: it should have been: for(int i=5;i>-1;i--)

Comment: The value of `column` won't change unless you change it.

Comment: Probably need to see the code where you are calling `inject(int column)` then.

Comment: But I don't change it!! The word "column" appears in my whole code only 6 times, the 6 you can see up there! And in no case I change the value of "column"

Comment: It doesn't change in the code you have shown us yes. But it could be changing where you call the method `inject()`. We can't help you until you provide the code where you are calling that method

Comment: You need to post a complete example. The variable `column` is not changed in `inject`. Therefore `inject(0)` cannot produce that output. Either you are calling `inject(1)` etc or the output comes from somewhere else.

Comment: You need some `break`s in that `switch`.

Comment: do I have to implement a break; after every case?

Comment: Yes, if you want the method to only be called with one value.

Comment: Okay, thank you to all of you! I just overslept to add it and don't concider to check the call of the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement `break;` after each `case:`